# Access a SignalR hub from a client using ws-trust

Tags: .net, signalr, federated-identity

I have a signalr hub thats on a website secured using federated authentication.

Is there anyway I can attach a saml token on my client app to allow communication with the signalr hub? I can't find any examples on line.

Thanks

Ross

Answer (score 1):

After speaking to David Fowler on twitter there is currently no way to add the token to the request so this isn't possible yet. Hopefully this will save someone some time!

Comment: I m actually on the same issue. Any news regarding this scenario?